# Rank Query Works in Mysql 5.5 but not working 5.6.20

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to calculate the rank index of the product , the query works fine in the local machine but the same query is not working in the live server.

**Local : Mysql 5.5.38
Live : Mysql 5.6.20**

### My Query

```
select 
    x . *
from
    (select 
        productID,
            productname,
            price,
            mobile_score,
            format((((5 / 100) * mobile_score) + (5 - (@ctrnk:=@ctrnk + 1) * (5 / (select 
                    count(*)
                from
                    product a
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ctrnk:=- 1) c
                join product b ON a.productID = b.productID
                where
                    a.mobile_score = 82 and a.categoryID != 13 and a.price > 0
                order by a.price asc)))) / 2, 2) as indexscore
    from
        product
    where
        mobile_score = 82 and categoryID != 13 and price > 0
    order by price asc) as x
where productID = 1923
```

### Output

```
Local :
    productID productname  price  mobile_score  indexscore
    1923      Xiaomi MI3   13999       82         4.55

Live :
    productID productname  price  mobile_score  indexscore
    1923      Xiaomi MI3   13999       82         Null
```

Comment: It probably does not work because you have different data on your life server. A calculation leads to an overflow or a divide by zero, is my guess. What if your `select count()` return `0`?

Comment: @juergend my select count(*) returns value i.e 6 in both the mysql versions.

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73283

Comment: @Raaga good catch on that defect report! Answer your own question so the next poor chap who hits this can benefit.

Comment: @Raaga: I don't get it. You don't use found_rows() anywhere. So what has that bug report to do with your question?

Comment: @juergend i checked in my both the version found_rows() after running my above query in mysql 5.5.38 i am getting fount_rows() 6 , where us in the mysql 5.6.20 i am getting found_rows() 0

Answer (score 0):

I found the this link regarding to my question.I think there is an bug in mysql 5.6.20 version [bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73283](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73283)

Comment: Please expand your question and answer so people know that the actual query is irrelevant and what you do later raised the bug (`found_rows()`) I recommend simplyfying the query to a simple `select count()`